# Swift 5 PickerView Array Count is not working properly enough to calucate user BMI using Height and Weight

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview

Used 2 PickerView Controllers with arrays to try to calculate user's BMI but the weight picker count gives me an Thread 1: Fatal  error: Index out of range.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?[iPhone StoryBoard image]

```
        //Height, Country and Weight Labels and Pickers
        @IBOutlet weak var bhLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var weightCalLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var heightbmiLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var heightScrollMenu: UIPickerView!
        @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var weightScrollMenu: UIPickerView!
        let heightToInches = (12...90).map { String($0) }
        let weightOptions  =  (50...600).map  { String($0) }

        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            if pickerView.tag == 31 {
                return weightOptions.count

            } else {
                return heightToInches.count
                }
            }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            if pickerView.tag == 30 {
                return "\(heightToInches[row])" + " Inches"
            }

            else {
                return "\(weightOptions[row])" + " Lbs"
            }
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if pickerView.tag == 30 {
                heightLabel.text = String(heightToInches[row]) + " Inches"
                heightbmiLabel.text = "(Height " + String(heightToInches[row]) + " Inches)²"
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 31 {
                weightLabel.text =  String(weightOptions[row]) + " lbs"
                weightCalLabel.text = "Weight " + String(weightOptions[row]) + " lbs"
            }
```

> Blockquote If I delete everything below then my app runs fine without any issues.

let stringHeight = self.heightToInches
                let IntHeight = Int(stringHeight[row])

```
            print(stringHeight[row])

            let stringWeight = self.weightOptions
```

> Blockquote  let IntWeight = Int(stringWeight[row]) 
>   This is where i get an error but whenever I delete this line of code then my app does not experience the Fatal Error: Index out of Range Error

```
   If I delete everything below this line then I can use both pickerviews without any issues and select any 

            print("IntWeight = \(IntWeight!).")

            let bmiconstant = 703

            let CalWeight = Int(IntWeight!)
            print("Cal Weight = \(CalWeight)")

            let CalHeight = Int(IntHeight!)
            print("CalHeight = \(CalHeight) ")

            let heightSquared = CalHeight * CalHeight
            print("HeightSquared = \(heightSquared)")

            let WeightDividedByHeight: Double = Double(CalWeight) / Double(heightSquared)

            let userBMI: Double = Double(bmiconstant) * Double(WeightDividedByHeight)

            print("user bmi = \(userBMI)")
            print("-------------------------")
            print("")
            print("")
            print("")
        }
```

Comment: This means your app believes that the row if outside the count of `stringWeight `. Which row are you selecting that is causing the error and what output do you get if you `print(stringWeight)` before where the error is?

Comment: @elliott-io I am selecting the Weight PickerView and once I get to 128 on my weightpicker the print(stringweight) is 91. Anything under 90 is okay but everything above 90 crashes the app

Comment: I noticed your heightToInches ends at 90. Are you sure you aren't accidentally called an index above 90 for it?

Comment: Such as this code not wrapped in the `if statement` to ensure the correct sender: `let stringHeight = self.heightToInches`  `let IntHeight = Int(stringHeight[row])`

Comment: Elliot! That seems to be the issue! I had to delete all that code and use an outside variable to convert my self.heightToinches[row] String to a Int. since the Pickerview seems to bug out using the previous old code

Comment: Great! Happy I could help you debug it. I'll put this into an answer.

Comment: Can you accept and upvote my answer when you get a chance? Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks and happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one your conversions in `didSelectRow` is calling an index outside or the data's range, such as:

```
let stringHeight = self.heightToInches 
let IntHeight = Int(stringHeight[row])
```

Make sure this is safely wrapped in an if statement or use `guard` to make sure it exists.